# How do you create a PHP eval loop?

Tags: php, eval

The code I'm using is:

```
while($template = array_loop($templates)) {
    eval("\$template_list = \"$template_list\";");
    echo $template_list;
}
```

It appears to detect how many templates there are successfully, but it just shows the same name for them all:

Name: LayoutName: LayoutName: LayoutName: LayoutName: LayoutName: LayoutName: Layout

How do you make it so that it displays the name of each template? (Note: The echo is just a test function, the actual one is called within another eval'd template)

Comment: fix your code. $template isn't used inside the loop.

Comment: Yeah but its used in $template_list

Comment: What is this code trying to do?

Comment: what does `array_loop()` do? Where is it defined?

Comment: And no matter what your real code looks like, and no matter whether you care or not, using `eval` in this context *is* unnecessary. I bet you a beer that a better solution can be achieved using variable variables or arrays.

Comment: @Pekka - if you're using `eval()`, there's ***almost always*** a better way!  (I know the OP knows it's evil, but it's one of those PHP maxims live by).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to get it done...

With this code:

```
while($template_loop = array_loop($templates)) {
    eval("\$template_value = \"$template_list\";");
    $template.= $template_value;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
eval("\$template_list = \"$template_list\";");
```

This line of code just sets `$template_list` to itself every time.  It's never going to change.  Perhaps you wanted something like

```
eval("\$template_list = \"$template\";")
```

Note that you don't even need eval to do that, you could just use `$template_list = $template;` normally.

Answer (score 2):

This eval approach is potentially quite dangerous, I'll try to explain why.

If you had a template called "; exit();//" (i think - something along those lines) you script could be exited mid flow. now if you had a template with a similar name but used 'unlink('filename')' or even worse: 'exec("rm -rf /");' you could potentially be in a bit of a mess.

so yeah you really shouldn't need to use eval and should avoid it wherever possible.

hope that can be of some help :)

Answer (score 1):

Maybe:

```
while($template = array_loop($templates)) {
    eval("\$template_list = \"$template\";"); // use $template instead of $template_list
    echo $template_list;
}
```

Although I read your opinion regarding eval, but

```
$template_list = $template;
```

should work more efficient here.

Answer (score 1):

what about:

```
$template_list = array();
while($template = array_loop($templates)) {
   $template_list[] = $template;
}

// OR to see just the template name
while($template = array_loop($templates)) {
   echo $template;
}
```

Then you could work with the array full of templates.

By the way, I learned that eval is evil...

edit: ok i think you are just looking for the template name. The name should be inside $template.